# Create email with the firsts letters of the name

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there any magic python way to get the firsts letters of each name and join with '@company.com' to create a email address?

Here is how I did:

```
name = ['Elon Reeve Musk']
full_name = [word[0].lower() for word in name[0].split(' ')]
firts_letters = "".join(full_name)
username = '%s@company.com' %(firts_letters)
```

The result is `erm@company.com`

Comment: And it works! It must be Python magic.

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: What exactly is your question? that code works

Comment: I know, I'm just looking for advanced Knowledge

Comment: Your method looks fine

Comment: Replace `word[0].lower()` to `word[0:3].lower()`

Comment: You could simplify to one line.  If name is a string not a list, you could use `'{}@ifpe.edu.br'.format(''.join([i[0].lower() for i in name.split()]))`

Comment: @Abhishakegupta That would result in `eloreemus@ifpe.edu.br`.

Comment: This is what I  guess  he means by saying get 1st 3 letters of each name

Comment: @Abhishakegupta He didn't say first three letters of each name.

Comment: @Abhishakegupta I only the first letter of each name

Comment: If the capitalization is always present:  `''.join([i for i in name[0] if i.isupper()]).lower()`

Comment: What advanced knowledge are you looking for? A modification of code? One-liner?

Comment: @AaronLael Nice advice

Comment: A more pythonic way to do my code @theausome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some "python magic"

```
name = ['Elon Reeve Musk']
f"{''.join(filter(str.isupper, name[0]))}@company.com".lower()
>>> erm@company.com
```

Whether this is better than your method is debatable. Most of the time a few lines of easy to read code is better than a one line hack.

My recommendation would be

```
name = ['Elon Reeve Musk']
initials = ''.join(word[0] for word in name[0].split())
f'{initials.lower()}@company.com'
>>> erm@company.com
```

Comment: Thanks for understand me, That's what I was looking for. Some suggestions from expert people.

Comment: @ItaloLemos you're welcome, although I'm far from an expert.